# Regex to select the text after matching character in multiline text

Tags: regexp-replace

I have the bellow text and I would like to remove the rest of each sentence after the first square bracket character. Can you please help? Thanks!

```
$10_Default_after_IGN[17357]_ Report [5 32 24 PM][5 29 2020].xml
$22_Default_or_Engineering_to_Extended[17358] _Report[5 32 55 PM][5 29 2020].xml
$3E_Default_to_Default[17363]_ Report [5 33 14 PM][5 29 2020].xml

Text after parsing

$10_Default_after_IGN
$22_Default_or_Engineering_to_Extended
$3E_Default_to_Default
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was not looking good enough. 
Bellow would do it :)

\[.*